# Exercise 14.1 from Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of Exercise 14.1 from Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory offered [Here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/braaten.1//qft/spring18/solutions14A.pdf)

For the most part, the proof makes sense to me. However, I am not sure how the equality on the second page is reached. In particular, how can we conclude things like
$$\int d^4x \int d^4 y \int d^4z J^*(z) M^{-1}(z,x) M(x,y)\phi(y) = \int d^4 z J^*(z)\phi(z)$$
This type of simplification is made repeatedly in this equality. Is this some kind of integral transform property? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The inverse sign on the first $M$ indicates that it will remove the second $M$. That is what it means for a kernel to be an inverse.

Comment: Just to put @flippiefanus 's comment into equations, the notation $M^{-1}$ means that the following identity is true (this is the definition of $M^{-1}$)
$$
\int d^4z M^{-1}(x, z) M(z, y) = \delta^{(4)}(x- y)
$$
You can use that to simplify the LHS of your equation.

Comment: Ok, so we are thinking of M as an integral transform. Thank you both!